# Is there a problem with formulas referencing custom variables?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, project-online

I am working with a SharePoint site that was set up by a consulting firm and I have noticed that when they have a custom variable that adds up the values in other custom variables, that instead of referencing the custom variables, they repeat the formulas for those variables.

Example:

```
Score A: User Entered
Score B: IIf([Funds Requested] > 0, 10, 0)
Score C: IIf(Len([Project Description]) < 1, 0, 2)
Total Score: [Score A] + IIf([Funds Requested] > 0, 10, 0) + 
   IIf(Len([Project Description]) < 1, 0, 2)
```

Why would they do the Total Score formula that way rather than just setting it to "[Score A] + [Score B] + [Score C]"?

I noticed that the field picker does not allow you to pick a custom field (it's not listed), though as far as I can determine, it works just fine if you manually type it in. I originally thought that this might be why they had done it the way they did, but the fact that they were able to use [Score A] seems to show that they were aware that they can use custom fields by bypassing the field picker.

My questions, considering the above, are these:

1. Do Custom fields that contain formulas break something if you reference them in another formula?
2. What possible reason could the consultants have had for entering the formula for the [Total Score] the way they did? Is this perhaps some holdover from older versions of SP?
3. Am I safe to change the formulas to reference the other fields (as it takes advantage of code reuse and is easier to read) if I am using SPO and these fields are used in a Project Online Site?

Question 3 is the important one, the others are more a matter of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

When asking about "custom fields", are you asking about Calculated Columns in a list? If so, these use IF, not IIF.

In any case, "=[Score A] + [Score B] + [Score C]" will work just fine.

> What possible reason could the consultants have had for entering the formula for the [Total Score] the way they did?

They may have created Total Score first, and later someone asked to see the values of Score B and Score C.

> Am I safe to change the formulas to reference the other fields (as it takes advantage of code reuse and is easier to read) if I am using SPO and these fields are used in a Project Online Site?

Should be. But you will see no measurable difference in performance.

Comment: These are Enterprise Custom Fields, which might be a Project thing, though I'm not sure how Project implements them using SharePoint primitives, so they might be Calculated Columns, but the formula definitely uses IIF, so perhaps not. Sorry I can't provide a firm answer on that.